# Weird ghost records in PostgreSQL - what are they?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I have a very weird issue on our postgresql DB. I have a table called "statement" which has some strange records in it.

Using the command line console psql, I query `select * from customer.statement where type in ('QUOTE');` and get 12 rows back. 7 rows look normal, 5 are missing all data except a single column which is a nullable column but seems to hold real values entered by the user. psql tells me that 7 rows were returned even though there are 12. Most of the other columns are not nullable. The weird records look like this:

```
select * from customer.statement where type = 'QUOTE';
        id        |    issuer_id     |   recipient_id   | recipient_name | recipient_reference | source_statement_id | catalogue_id | reference | issue_date |  due_date  |                           description                            |   total   | currency | type  | tax_level | rounding_mode |  status   | recall_requested |        time_created        |        time_updated        | time_paid 
------------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+---------------+-----------+------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------
 ... 7 valid records removed ...
                  |                  |                  |                |                     |                     |              |           |            |            | Build bulkheads and sheet with plasterboard.                    +|           |          |       |           |               |           |                  |                            |                            | 
                  |                  |                  |                |                     |                     |              |           |            |            | Patch all patches.                                              +|           |          |       |           |               |           |                  |                            |                            | 
                  |                  |                  |                |                     |                     |              |           |            |            | Set and sand all joints ready for painting.                     +|           |          |       |           |               |           |                  |                            |                            | 
                  |                  |                  |                |                     |                     |              |           |            |            | Use wall angle on bulkhead in main bedroom.                     +|           |          |       |           |               |           |                  |                            |                            | 
                  |                  |                  |                |                     |                     |              |           |            |            | Build nib and sheet and set in entrance                          |           |          |       |           |               |           |                  |                            |                            | 
(7 rows)
```

If I run the same query using pgAdmin, I don't see those weird records.

Anyone know what these are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plus sign before the separator (`+|`) indicates a newline character in the displayed string value in **psql**. So no additional rows, just the same row continued with line breaks. The final line of output in your quote confirms as much: `(7 rows)`.

In pgAdmin you don't see the extra lines as long as you don't increase the height of the field (or copy / paste the content somewhere), but there are multiple lines as well.

Try in psql and in pgAdmin:

```
test=# SELECT E'This\nis\na\ntest.' AS multi_line, 'foo' AS single_line;
  multi_line  | single_line
--------------+-------------
 This        +| foo
 is          +|
 a           +|
 test.        |
(1 row)
```

[The manual about psql:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

> `linestyle`
>
> Sets the border line drawing style to one of `ascii`, `old-ascii`, or `unicode`. [...] The default setting is `ascii`. [...]
>
> `ascii` style uses plain ASCII characters. Newlines in data are shown using a `+` symbol in the right-hand margin. [...]

Comment: Ahhhh! I understand. psql is printing each new line in the description column like it presents individual records. So there are 7 records, not 12. Thanks. Makes sense.